# Publishing to github results in an empty repository

Tags: github

I am new to git. I downloaded the desktop version (for Windows). I dragged the folder containing my project into the big window, "Get started by adding a repository." All the files showed up in the left window. Then I clicked on "Publish Repository". It then shows 143 files have changed, with 0 unsynced.

But when I go to my account on the git website, the repository is empty. The only files in it are `.gitattributes` and `.gitignore`. The whole idea here is that I want to share this project with other people.

Help out a git newbie and explain how I get the entire solution into git?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you already have the remote repository at GitHub, you should use the `clone` option first to clone your repository locally.

This will create a folder (your repository clone) on the default location containing those two files.

Then you can copy your project files to this folder and try to sync again.